# Can there be a hierarchy of activities in Android?

Tags: java, android, hierarchy

So I am building a mobile banking application. The first activity is the `LoginActivity`. If the user enters the correct credentials, a new activity is opened, `HomePageActivity`. Here is a `FrameLayout` that can be switch between 4 fragments: `HomeFragment`, `TransactionsFragment`, `TransfersFragment`, `ReportsFragment`. In the `HomeFragment` is a button that when pressed, a `DialogFragment` appears : `AddDepositFragment`. And so on. I have included a picture representing the "hierarchy".
And now the question is: CAN this be considered a hierarchy?[image]

Comment: Define what you mean by hierarchy.  Can you organize your app like this?  Sure, although you'll probably want homepage activity to redirect to LoginActivity if the user times out or the login becomes invalid.  But your question seems to be asking for something more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Activities` are organised in the `stack`. Each `Activity` you have been opened is put on the top of this `stack`.

`Android` supports modification of such behaviour, e.g. newly opened `Activity` is put in the new `stack`. To learn more about possible options check [this official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack#TaskLaunchModes).

A case of multi-window mode requires more investigation.

From your question I understand what you have been asking about. The term 'hierarchy' is usually used in traditional terms of `OOP` and it is also supported in both `Java` or `Kotlin` `Android`: you could create a `BaseActivity()` and extend it for both `LoginActivity` and `HomePageActivity`.